# How to georeference an image dynamically

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing, image, php

I am looking for dynamic approach how to georeference an image of a radar. This is a data that is going to be fetch every hour. Of course I will only need radar data (without base layer and borders) which means I will have to extract it, but before that (as I am going to move marks and lables of cities) I would like to georeference it. Image looks like this:

[image: non georeferenced image]

Main cities and smaller cities are marked with diamonds (bigger for main cities/smaller for smaller cities). [image: Main city] [image: city]

In general, what I am able to find out (for example over google maps) are coordinates of this cities as points of interests. I assume this task could be somehow done with GDAL or/and python but I am pretty much lost since I only use PHP and for this kind of tasks until now I only used Desktop GIS since I havent had need to use it for dynamic tasks.

Any help will be preety much appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not the full solution, but an idea where to go: If the raster data always shows the same area in the same resolution, you may save your reference points and let the georeferencer produce a GDAL-script for you (Ctrl+C when in the georeferencing window). This - and naturally GDAL itself - you could incoorporate into your usual workflow.

Comment: Thanks! This is preety much handy for starters! Will come back with an outcome!